# Angular: Data Binding between a page and component nor working in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, data-binding, ionic4, angular-components

I am not able to pass data from a page to a component using data binding.

When I tried to log the value in the constructor it says it is undefined. *message* is the name of variable that is being used to achieve data binding.

**app-floating-text-white.ts ( component )**

```
import { Component, OnInit ,Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-floating-text-white',
  templateUrl: './floating-text-white.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./floating-text-white.component.scss'],
})
export class FloatingTextWhiteComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input() message: string;

 constructor() { 
   console.log(this.message)
 }

 ngOnInit() {}

}
```

**app-floating-text-white.html ( component )**

```
<p> {{message}} </p>
```

**page.html**

```
<app-floating-text-white [message]="Hello World"> </app-floating-text-white>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. In your app-floating-text-white.ts the message variable is undefined until the binding "kicks in". So when console.log is called int he constructor (which happens at component creation time) the value of message is still undefined.

During the closest CDR cycle the binding will be refreshed and a new value "Hello World" will be passed into your child component.

Try adding the ngAfterViewInit { console.log(this.message) } and see what happens after all the bindings were refreshed (ngAfterViewInit is triggered after all bindings were checked and refreshed).

also i notes you use single quotes here to bind value:

```
<app-floating-text-white [message]="Hello World"> </app-floating-text-white>
```

the above code would expect Hello World to be a variable. You need to make it a string:

```
<app-floating-text-white [message]="’Hello World’"> </app-floating-text-white>
```

Or bind to actual variable of your page.ts

Comment: I tried { console.log(this.message) } in ngAfterViewInit and I still get the value as undefined.

Comment: can you try instead of this: [message]=“Hello World” do [message]=“‘Hello World’” - basically take Hello World into additional quotes?